# NodeJS HTTP GET returns empty body

Tags: ajax, node.js, http

Here's a NodeJS code snippet I'm debugging. The url is correct, and a GET request to it with [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) returns a `200 OK` with the following headers. The response body is a valid JSON string.

### Headers (arrows represent column divisors)

```
Accept-Ranges →bytes
Age →0
Cache-Control →max-age=300
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →255
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Tue, 24 Jan 2017 22:37:28 GMT
Expires →Tue, 24 Jan 2017 17:47:43 GMT
Last-Modified →Tue, 24 Jan 2017 01:03:08 GMT
Server →nginx
Vary →Accept-Encoding
Via →1.1 varnish
X-Cache →HIT
X-Cache-Hits →1
X-Served-By →cache-yul8926-YUL
X-Timer →S1485297448.259768,VS0,VE89
```

### The problem:

I've discovered that `res.on('data', function(chunk) {` never gets called which causes `body` to remain empty.

When `res.on('end', function() {` is called  `body` still has length = 0. Any ideas why the data callback is not getting called?

```
http.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      cb(data, undefined);
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("Something went wrong");
  console.log(err);
});
```

Also worth nothing, `cb` is a callback function defined outside of this snippet.

Comment: Add a `.on('error', ...)` handler as in `http.get(...).on('error', fn)` to see if you are getting an error reported.  Also, check `res.statusCode`.

Comment: I actually forgot to include the `.on('error', ...)` handler. I updated the question to include it. Great tip with `res.statusCode` - that got me in the right direction to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

After the lovely advice from jfriend00 I discovered that `res.statusCode` was `301` (Moved Permanently). Seems that the website was redirecting to the same URL but with `https` protocol instead of `http`.

When testing the REST API with Postman it did not mention the fact the request was redirected. <strike>Postman displayed a `200` OK response (???)</strike> According to the [Postman Docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/handling_redirects) it will default to following redirects silently.

#### The solution:

I replaced all instances of `http` with `https` and it worked great.

```
https.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
      cb(data, undefined);
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("Something went wrong");
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: From the [Postman doc](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/handling_redirects): "By default, Postman will follow the Location header in all 301/302 responses automatically."

Comment: Thanks. Wish I'd known that earlier haha. Would have saved me lots of time. That's what I get for making assumptions.